# MVC3 recursive nested webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I'm having some trouble nesting webgrids.

As long as I only have to have 1 webgrid inside another, it's fine, but once I try to nest a webgrid in an already nested webgrid, it fails.

This is the code I have:

```
@grid.GetHtml(columns:
grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("Name"),
    grid.Column("Variants", format: (item) =>
    {
        WebGrid varGrid = varGrid = new WebGrid(item.Variant);
        return varGrid.GetHtml(
                columns: varGrid.Columns(
                    varGrid.Column("Name")

                ),
                displayHeader : false
        );
    }),
    grid.Column("Resource", format: (item) =>
    {
        WebGrid resGrid = new WebGrid(item.Resource);
        return resGrid.GetHtml(
            columns: resGrid.Columns(
                resGrid.Column("Name"),
                resGrid.Column("Parameters", format: (item) =>
                {
                    WebGrid resParamGrid = new WebGrid(item.Resource.Parameter);
                    return resParamGrid.GetHtml(
                    columns: resParamGrid.Columns(
                            resParamGrid.Column("Name")
                            ),
                            displayHeader: false
                        );
                })
            ),
            displayHeader: false
        );
    }),
    grid.Column("Parameter", format: (item) =>
    {
        WebGrid parGrid = new WebGrid(item.Parameter);
        return parGrid.GetHtml(
            columns: parGrid.Columns(
                    parGrid.Column("Name")
            ),
            displayHeader: false
        );
    })
)
)
```

So the grid has another grid, `Resources`. Every `Resources` grid has a grid containing the Parameters.

In VS there is no error, but when I try to run the application, it return as error:

> "Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.Column(string, string, System.Func, string, bool)' has some invalid arguments"

With a pointer to this spot:

`grid.Column("Resource", format: (item) =>`

Is it not possible to have recursive nested webgrids, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with you repeating the `item` variable twice. Try renaming it:

```
grid.Column("Resource", format: (item) =>
{
    WebGrid resGrid = new WebGrid(item.Resource);
    return resGrid.GetHtml(
        columns: resGrid.Columns(
            resGrid.Column("Name"),
            resGrid.Column("Parameters", format: (resource) =>
            {
                WebGrid resParamGrid = new WebGrid(resource.Parameter);
                return resParamGrid.GetHtml(
                    columns: resParamGrid.Columns(
                        resParamGrid.Column("Name")
                    ),
                    displayHeader: false
                );
            })
        ),
        displayHeader: false
    );
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much. can't belive i didn't catch that myself